# Como implementar Lombok no projeto Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Eu estou problemas nessa classe, dá uma olhada

```
@Service
public class CadastroEstiloService {

    @Autowired
    private Estilos estilos;

    @Transactional
    public void salvar(Estilo estilo) {
        Optional<Estilo> estiloOptional = estilos.findByNomeIgnoreCase(estilo.getNome());
        if (estiloOptional.isPresent()) {
            throw new NomeEstiloJaCadastradoException("Nome do estilo já cadastrado");
        }

        estilos.save(estilo);
    }

}
```

Não está conseguindo reconhecer o **getNome** depois que alterei minha entidade ao implementar o Lombok

verifiquem o a minha entidade antes das alterações;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "estilo")
public class Estilo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    @NotBlank(message = "O nome é obrigatório")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "O tamanho do nome não pode ser maior que {max} caracteres")
    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "estilo")
    private List<Cerveja> cervejas;

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Estilo other = (Estilo) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Minha entidade depois das alterações;

```
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "estilo")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Estilo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter @Setter
    private Long codigo;

    @NotBlank(message = "O nome é obrigatório")
    @Size(max = 20, message = "O tamanho do nome não pode ser maior que {max} caracteres")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "estilo")
    @Getter @Setter
    private List<Cerveja> cervejas;


}
```

eu seguir esse site para mim guiar [CLIQUE AQUI](http://blog.caelum.com.br/java-menos-verboso-com-lombok/)

Aceito sugestões!

Adicionei o Lombok através do Maven;

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Os *getters* e *setters* ("getNome", por exemplo) serão gerados durante a compilação do projeto. Ative o build automático da IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans...) e ao incluir as anotações salve todos os arquivos alterados antes de esperar que os *getters* e *setters* sejam reconhecidos. Experimente também fazer um clean/build do projeto - a compilação automática da IDE pode ter falhado ou ficado incompleta na primeira tentativa.

Comment: Você realizou a instalação do Lombok na sua IDE, conforme o tutorial ensina? Qual IDE você utiliza?

Comment: eu adicionei o Lombok atravé do maven, ele conseguiu pegar a versão Lombok 1.16.12, detalhe, o meu projeto já está com build ativado e fechei e abri o projeto e dei um clear no projeto e nada de resultado.

Comment: Eu estou usando a IDE Eclipse

Comment: pessoal ainda preciso de ajuda!

Comment: Na sua IDE você já instalou/configurou o plugin do lombok? Tente compilar com o maven(`mvn compile`), e nos forneça mais detalhes sobre o erro, um stacktrace seria interessante.

Comment: Não esqueça que estou trabalhando com Maven, eu incluir o artefato no arquivo pom.xml em seguida salvai e dei clear no projeto, o Eclipse está com o build no automático, mesmo depois de ter feito isso, eu cliquei com o direito no mouse no projeto fui em Maven -> Update Project, e mesmo assim não resolveu. O projeto não gerar mensagens de erros. O que posso fazer é criar um simples projeto que implemente  o Lombok e colocar-lo no GitHub para analise.

Comment: Não basta colocar a dependência maven. Você precisa instalar o Lombok TAMBÉM na IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente adicionar as anotações: @Getter @Setter

@Getter 
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "estilo")
public class Estilo implements Serializable {